# Snowflake - system/built-in stored procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any stored procedure shipped by Snowflake?

```
SHOW PROCEDURES IN ACCOUNT;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) WHERE "is_builtin" != 'N';
-- 0 rows

SHOW FUNCTIONS IN ACCOUNT;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) WHERE "is_builtin" != 'N';
--  571
```

We have quite extensive function list, but I am unable to locate a single stored procedure.

Some of the functions(e.g. `SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES`) contain side-effects, which means they could be stored procedures(they even support execution via [CALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/call.html)):

```
SELECT SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES(CURRENT_SESSION()::INT);
CALL SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES(CURRENT_SESSION()::INT);
```

Is there any rationale behind this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake has been an evolving product over the last 6 year. When it was first released there was no support for dynamic SQL aka Procedures, and there was very little support for Database introspection, like you have in the system table of PostgreSQL.

So many of the "do X" or "tell me about Y" where done via rather ugly function calls, that clearly showed you where escaping the sandpit (as compared to PostgreSQL where of db health/state is also "tables"). I remember our team coding up support to read results from the SHOW commands because RESULT_SCAN did not exist.

So the platform has changed a lot, and now using a mental model of "functions" only read, "procedures" alter mindset, it seems things to do fit the model.

Comment: That makes more sense. Normal UDF functions cannot have side-effects,SF can so yes, functions were used in lieu of non-existing procedures at a time.